# JBoss 7 classloading miracles

Tags: java, osgi, jboss7.x, classloader

I have problems with a webservice/OSGi application that is bundled as WAR under JBoss 7.

My questions are:

1. What modules are available to the application by default? I know how to add a dependeny and how to exclude one. But how do I know the defaults? I think they are called "global modules".
2. Which packages of the JDK are provided to the application by default? All? Some? How do I investigate this?
3. By concrete error is the following. Some bootstrapping code calls `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()`. Which results in the exception `javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory not found`. It seems as in JBoss the system property `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` points to the above strange implementation `__redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just found a good starting point in the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

1. Modules added implicitly are described in detail in the JBoss documentation found here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments. As the other answer already states, dependencies can be suppressed by declaring excludes in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.
2. See answer above
3. The application deployed to JBoss is a WAR file that itself bootstraps an OSGi container. Inside the container Gemini Blueprint is used to manage OSGi service dependencies. Gemini Blueprint searches for Spring Application Context files and starts a Spring context for the bundle if found. Parsing the XML file failed with the exception stated above. The reason was that the package `__redirected` was not avaiable to the bundle. I managed this via boot delegation.

   ```
   # In JBoss some JDK classes like "javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory" are redirected to a JBoss package "__redirected" via a system property
   # The corresponding implementation "__redirected/__DocumentBuilderFactory" is made accessible from all bundles via "boot delegation" 
   org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation = __redirected
   # Sets the parent classloader to the one that loads the framework. It must have access to the bootdelegation pakages, e. g. "__redirected"
   org.osgi.framework.bundle.parent = framework
   ```

Comment: how do you know gemini blueprint is being used? I don't see anything about that in OP

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check the admin console / OSGi tab to see what are available for you on runtime. "By default" depends on your startup configuration, there are 4 alternative startup profiles that you can use IIRC.
2. Check $JBOSS/modules/sun/jdk/main/module.xml to see which packages are imported and which not. Only some of them are. Others you need to add manually by [using jboss-deployment-structure](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7) or modifying sun.jdk module.xml file if you need them. There are other automatic dependencies in addition to JDK, which are listed on [this page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments).
3. You'll need to provide more details to answer this, including your dependencies. Xerces parser is a big headache for a modular classloader.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the using of the method setContextClassLoader. This override the classloder which can load the DocumentBuilderFactory. A workaround is to use OrderClassLoaders.

```
Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
ClassLoader originalCl = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
currentThread.setContextClassLoader( new OrderClassLoaders( myCl, originalCl ) );
```